# How do I enable C++ warnings for mismatch in string format

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compiler-warnings

In some current C++ code something along the lines of:

float f = 22.8f;
object.printf("%s \n", f);

is causing a crash. It is a pain to search for this crap in the code. I am wondering if I can enable certain warnings in VS2010 to help me find these errors.

Unfortunately the compiler isn't capturing this with warning along the lines of "format string doesn't match your arguments", maybe I don't have it enabled, or it isn't supported in visual studio 2010.

Comment: Yes.. this object has its own printf

Comment: but forgot to mention the object's printf behaves the same way that the regular printf.

Comment: `printf` does not validate the format string, and in fact will crash or otherwise behave badly with the wrong data. This is one reason to prefer iostreams in C++ over the C counterpart.

Comment: Any ideas how I can validate that at compile time to check for places where it will crash

Comment: Yes, use iostreams instead of `printf` style variable argument functions. `float f = 22.8f; object.out << f;` <-- correct `operator<<` for float is called.

Comment: I can't do that. It's everywhere in the code, and I can't modify the object to support the << operator. The object is provided by third party I can't change it.

Comment: If that is the case, code very carefully. Even if VS2010 support such a message, it would not apply here since it would not know anything about the object's `printf` and the library code probably would not be checked.